# Looking for a tool that centralized collaboration of documents + code + tickets ,

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration, redmine

I want to set up a central project management tool and also a CI server, I'm looking for ideas. Our code is in C++ visual studio/.NET , our app's are mainly windows desktop apps...We have just SVN. The tool must be in-house and not SaaS. We are a very small start-up (3 developers) without extra resources.
What do you think should a good start for a collaboration tool that centralized documents + code + tickets What do you think about Wikis ? Redmine Wiki?
Do you have a case study that can help me? 
Do you have a good idea how to approach such enviorments ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/) tools suite.

JIRA is their issue tracker, Confluence is their wiki, and they have Stash/bitbucket for a code repository. I haven't used their code repository solutions (we use Mercurial in my shop), but I have used JIRA and Confluence and both are pretty decent tools. They don't seem to get in the way at all, which is a welcome change of pace.

Since you're a small shop, you can probably get by with the starter licenses ($10/product for usually up to 10 users). You can either install the tools locally and manage the server yourself, or they have hosted options for a monthly fee (if you want to save yourselves the hassle of managing backups etc, that might be a good way to cut down on distractions).

Comment: Jira + Atlassian could be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your are working with Microsoft technologies, perhaps the best option is [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181238%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However there are other ways to get a good development ecosystem:

1. Build your own (install the tools what you want and support it)
2. Use a pre-concibed dev ecosystem

I think you are looking for 2, and there are also options:

1. [Clinker](http://clinkerhq.com) (SCM, issue tracker, wiki, document manager)
2. [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) (SCM, issue tracker, wiki)
3. [Stash](http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview) (SCM, issue tracker (optional))
4. [GitHub](http://github.com) (SCM, issue tracker)

Assembla has no self-hosted version, so the filter only pass Clinker, Stash and GitHub. At this point start your work: compare and select.